# How to use OnFocousChange for mvvmcross in android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to detect `OnFocousChange` for `editText` in xamarin to close the keyboard o'clock of outside edit text

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                hideKeyboard(v);
            }
        }
});
```

Since `setOnFocusChangeListener` is not available in xamarin, I tried with

```
    staticTextFragrance.FocusChange += (object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e) => {
                    hideKeyboard();
};
```

It is not Working, How to resolve this !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using androids input manager to detect when a tap anywhere other than your textedit box is handled, and dismiss the keyboard accordingly. You definately wouldn't want to have to handle unfocus events for every control that requires input. So a more global approach is the standard pattern.

heres a rough example:

```
private EditText tbUsername;
private EditText tbPassword;
private InputMethodManager imm;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

      SupportActionBar.Title = "Login";

      FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLogin).Click += LoginActivity_Click;

      tbUsername= FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.tbUsername);
      tbPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.tbPassword);

      imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
 }

private async void LoginActivity_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
      imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(tbUsername.WindowToken, 0);
      imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(tbPassword.WindowToken, 0);
}
```

The Xamarin Developer guide for this can be found at this [Link.](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager/)

Answer (score 2):

**This can also be done by:**

```
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
     hideKeyboard();
         return base.DispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

---

```
public void hideKeyboard()
    {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        var currentFocus = CurrentFocus;
        if (currentFocus != null)
        {
            inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);

        }
    }
```